# ng build issue: Error: Unknown argument: base-href/

Tags: angularjs, github-pages, ng-build

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLLTj.png)

The above error is what i have issued when i was trying to build the angular project for external hosting, using the ng build command, anyone faced this issue ?

Tying to run the ng build for angular project
expecting to run the command which generates the docs folder with files for the external build.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the issue,

So the solution is that we need to keep the space after the "href" in the command
    `href/<repo name> is wrong href /<repo name> is correct.`
[Check the changes after updating the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZy2D.png)